# USB Linux full installation shutdown problem

Tags: ubuntu, usb, shutdown, unmount

I am booting Lubuntu 17.04 from an USB device. I made a full installation on it!
Everytime after a shutdown I have fsck problems if I boot from the USB device.

I think the USB device will not be unmounted before the device shuts down. But I am really not sure.

How can I unmount the USB device the OS is running on shutdown?

Thank you very much for your advices!

Best regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12767/does-shutdown-p-now-safely-unmount-a-usb-drive-mounted-to-dev-sdb1) help you. And you can also skip a `fsck` by updating `/etc/fstab` file.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bypassing-fsck/

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, that solved skipping the fsck!
Have a nice weekend @iadd!